# Closed-form solution of the recurrence relation $f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)+f(m-1,n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

I'm working with the recurrence relation $f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)+f(m-1,n-1)$, with the boundary condition $f(m,0)=f(0,n)=1$.

After some work, it is not hard to show the generating function is $F(x,y):=\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}f(m,n)x^my^n=\frac{1}{1-x-y-xy}$.

Computing $f(m,n)$ seems rather cumbersome because a trinomial expansion is involved. The furtherest I could go is
$$
f(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)}\frac{(n+m-k)!}{(n-k)!(m-k)!k!}
$$

I'm wondering if $f(m,n)$ could be further simplified?

Comment: I feel like drawing a tree and then counting the leaves could be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number) and there is no "simple" formula, you can't further simplify your expression, but you can get some alternatives on the wikipedia page or at [OEIS A008288](https://oeis.org/A008288), for example:

$$
f(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}2^k
$$